# Casting a pointer to a union to a pointer to the element type of an array member of the union

Tags: arrays, c, language-lawyer, union, undefined-behavior

I have a `union`:

```
union Obj64 {
    uint64_t u64;
    uint32_t u32[2];
    uint16_t u16[4];
    uint8_t u8[8];
};
static_assert(sizeof(union Obj64) == sizeof(uint64_t), "Unexpected trailing padding in union!");
```

Now I have a pointer to the `union`:

```
union Obj64 *union_ptr = SOME_VALUE;
```

I want a `uint16_t *` pointer to the same data. I could access the `u16` member and use that as a `uint16_t *` due to [pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/16217248):

```
uint16_t *u16_ptr = union_ptr->u16;
```

But would casting the `union` to a `uint16_t *` directly be valid?

```
uint16_t *u16_ptr = (uint16_t *)union_ptr;
```

I know that:

> A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bitfield, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

But the `union` does not contain any isolated `uint16_t` members but only a `uint16_t` *array.* So does the above rule apply?

1. Is the above conversion valid?
2. Are there any differences in terms of (un)defined behavior when using the pointer **if** the above conversion is valid in the first place?

   For example I might have a buffer of multiple `union Obj64` objects. Could I use `((uint16_t *)union_ptr)[4]` to access a `uint16_t` inside **the next** `union` in the buffer [even though using `union_ptr->u16` to do so would not be valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76467975/16217248)

Comment: Both the existing answers give conflicting information as to whether that cast is valid in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not formally define the supported conversions, so trying to language-lawyer these is to some extent futile. C 2018 6.7.2.1 16 says “… A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa,” but nothing in the standard defines “suitably converted.”

`(uint16_t *)union_ptr` produces a pointer to a `uint16_t`. None of the members of `Obj64` is a `uint16_t`, so this does not point to any of its members, so 6.7.2.1 16 does not apply even if “suitably converted” is defined. The `u16` member is an array, so `(uint16_t (*)[4]) union_ptr` is almost certainly a “suitably converted” pointer to that member.

Even if you consider `(uint16_t *)union_ptr` to be first a conversion to the array and then a conversion to a pointer to its first member, the C standard does not actually define the latter conversion. Given `int x[4];`, `(int *) &x` is a partially defined conversion (it produces a pointer that can be converted back to `int (*)` to produce a pointer to the array), but it is not defined to necessarily point to `x[0]`. (It does in plenty of normal C implementations, but this is a language-lawyer question.)

You can produce a pointer to the first element of the `u16` member by using `* (uint16_t (*)[4]) union_ptr` designate the array and allowing array-to-pointer conversion to occur, or you could take it explicitly with `&((uint16_t (*)[4]) union_ptr)[0]`. Or simply use `union_ptr->u16` with pointer-to-array conversion.

In any case, once you get a pointer to `union_ptr->u16[0]` by any method, you can use it to access `union_ptr->u16[i]` for 0 ≤ `i` < 4. Using it to access the memory beyond that is not safe without some additional prerequisite.

> … would `((uint16_t *)union_ptr)[x]` be safe if `x > 3` and `union_ptr` was a pointer to an element in a `Obj64` array and there was an element after?

No. Why would it be? `((uint16_t *)union_ptr)[x]` includes arithmetic on, at best, a pointer to an element in an array, and that array has elements indexed from 0 to 3, and arithmetic on that pointer is not defined if the index it would refer to goes beyond 4. It is defined for 4, but dereferencing the pointer is not. The fact that `Obj64` contains an array of 4 `uint16_t` does not mean that an array of, say, 2 `Obj64` contains an array of 8 `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid to convert a pointer to a `union` to a pointer to any of its members and back.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.2.1p16 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its
> members. The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a
> union object at any time. **A pointer to a union object, suitably
> converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-
> field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.**

This doesn't however change the behavior mentioned in the linked question.  What you're essentially asking is, given `uint16_t x[4][4]`, whether accessing `x[0][4]` is valid.  The answer to that is no, as the linked question states.

So `union_ptr->u16[4]` and `((uint16_t *)union_ptr)[4]` are both undefined behavior.

Comment: `(uint16_t *)union_ptr` does not convert a pointer to a union to a pointer to any of its members, since it has no `uint16_t` member.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But does that change anything?

Comment: @user16217248: Yes, the question is tagged language-lawyer, and none of the language in the C standard says a conversion from a pointer to a union to a pointer to the type of an element of the member of a union is defined. Technically, what `(uint16_t *)union_ptr` points to is not defined in the C standard.